# Decrease the width of column in a GridLayout

Tags: kivy

I have this code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class TedeGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TedeGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 3
        self.img = Image(source='sriyantra.png')
        self.add_widget(self.img)
        self.add_widget(Label(text="HELLO"))

        self.inside = GridLayout()
        self.inside.cols = 1

        self.add_widget(self.inside)

        self.next_button = Button(text="Next")
        self.inside.add_widget(self.next_button)

        self.prev_button = Button(text="Prev")
        self.inside.add_widget(self.prev_button)

class Tedegraph(App):
    def build(self):
        return TedeGrid()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Tedegraph().run()
```

I would like to decrease the width of the third column, to be e.g. 10% of the width of the first column.

Even better would be, if there wasn't a button, but on the right would be a small tap area (which reacts to `next` event) and on the left would be a small tap area (which reacts to `prev` event)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this, I redesigned your code a little, I hope it makes sense. Is this how you wanted it to be? If you can't understand how to change something, tell me and I will change/explain it for/to you!

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class Tedegraph(App):
    def build(self): # I will add everything here
        # For your example, it's better to use boxlayout, you don't want a table/grid like pattern, right?
        mainbox = BoxLayout(orientation="horizontal", # Create the main box layout and make it horizontal
                            spacing=15, # Add spacing between widgets
                            padding=5) # And padding on the sides
        mainbox.add_widget(Button(text="Prev", # Add the prev button
                                  font_size="17dp", # set font size
                                  size_hint=(.3, .2), # make the button smaller
                                  pos_hint={"center_x":0.5, # Center it on the x
                                            "center_y":0.5}, # And on the y
                                  on_press=self.prevscreen)) # Attach a button function
        mainbox.add_widget(Image(source='sriyantra.png')) # Add your image after the button
        mainbox.add_widget(Label(text="HELLO")) # And add the text
        mainbox.add_widget(Button(text="Next", # Add the next button and set the same parameters for the next button
                                  font_size="17dp",
                                  size_hint=(.3, .2),
                                  pos_hint={"center_x":0.5,
                                            "center_y":0.5},
                                  on_press=self.nextscreen)) # And change the button press function
        return mainbox


     # I created the functions for you
    def nextscreen(self, *args):
        print("Clicked Next")
        # Here you can write the code that you want to do when the prev button is pressed

    def prevscreen(self, *args):
        print("Clicked Prev")
        # Here you can write the code that you want to do when the next button is pressed

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Tedegraph().run()
```

Comment: Please, how would you positition a small widget (combobox), to the bottom of the screen? I don't want it to take space on the right, which is default position, I'd like to bind it rather to the bottom. Thank you.

Comment: @xralf You can use a vertical box layout instead of horizontal, in this case: mainbox = BoxLayout(orientation="horizontal", spacing=15, padding=5)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a big grid layout, where I would put smaller grid layouts and adjust the size of each of the smaller ones using `size_hint=(width, height)`

If you want a code example, can you please add the photo you use in the code so I can run it properly?

Comment: Thank you, [here](https://ibb.co/LSv3dQh) is the photo.